# How do I append to a YAML file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a YAML file called `data.yaml`:

```
---
'001':
  name: Ben
  email: ben@test.com
```

I would like to have an updated file that looks like this:

```
---
'001':
  name: Ben
  email: ben@test.com
'002':
  name: Lisa
  email: lisa@test.com
  numbers: 
    - 000-111-2222
    - 000-111-2223
```

How do I achieve this in python using yaml package/s?

Edit:

I have tried:

```
import yaml
import io

data = {'002': {'name': 'Lisa', 'email': 'lisa@test.com', 'numbers': ['000-111-2222', '000-111-2223']}}

with io.open('data.yaml', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    yaml.safe_dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)
```

Method *safe_dump* overrides the file content and I only see this as the new file content!

```
'002':
  name: Lisa
  email: lisa@test.com
  numbers: 
    - 000-111-2222
    - 000-111-2223
```

Comment: Parse file using any yaml parser, edit your dict accordingly and save it to the same file. [Here's](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) one of the parsers:

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Klaus D.import io                                                                                                              
import yaml                                                                                                         
data = {'002'{'name':'Lisa', 'email':'lisa@test.com', 'numbers':['000-111-2222','000-111-2223']}}                                                                                                           
with io.open('data.yaml', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    yaml.update(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False, allow_unicode=True)

Comment: Add your code to the question. It is not readable in a comment.

Comment: @KlausD. I just edited the question for you to see what I've tried so far. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Becks I grepped for a function `update` in the PyYAML sources, but it doesn't seem to be there. There is a method `update`, but it doesn't have that signature. Are you sure that code did work, and that you were not looking at old results?

Comment: @Anthon you are correct. Update spills : module 'yaml' has no attribute 'update' ... So, what gives? how do I append a YAML file with a dictionary as mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, in general, not add to a YAML document in a file by just writing extra
information at the end of that file.  This migth work for YAML documents that have
a mapping or sequence at the top level that is block style, but even
then simply appending can only work for certain cases of documents.

It is easy to just load your YAML to Python datastructure,
update/extend that structure and then dump it back. That way you don't
have to deal with potential duplicate keys, non-bare documents and
other issues that will result in invalid YAML when you use simple
appending. Assumping your original file is called `input.yaml`, the
following does the trick:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

file_name = Path('input.yaml')

record_to_add = dict(name='Lisa', email='lisa@test.com', numbers=['000-111-2222', '000-111-2223'])

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.explicit_start = True
data = yaml.load(file_name)
data['002'] = record_to_add
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
---
'001':
  name: Ben
  email: ben@test.com
'002':
  name: Lisa
  email: lisa@test.com
  numbers:
  - 000-111-2222
  - 000-111-2223
```

Comment: Using python3 : Any idea on how do I write that sys.stdout output back into the same inputs.yaml ?

Comment: @Becks `yaml.dump(data, file_name)`  See the second example in [this section of the documentation](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=pathlib#departure-from-previous-api)

Comment: The second parameter to `dump` can either be a `pathlib.Path`, which will then be opened for writing appropriately, or a file pointer like `sys.stdout`, `fp` while doing `with open('somefile.yaml', 'wb') as fp`, or an `io.BytesIO` instance.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Anthon.